# Generic hash codes in Java

Tags: java, hashcode

I am somewhat new to Java. Is there is a hashcode utility class that can generate a good hash code for a generic object with members of arbitrary types inside the class? Can I recursively step through the instance of a generic java object and accumulate a hash code that guarantees two equal objects of this class will always compute the same hash code? **The context of this question is Android and the Objects.hashCode() etc is not available to me in the Java version I am using (and I have no option to migrate to a newer version).**
I am guessing the answer is no based on what I have seen so far.

Comment: There's a java.lang.Object.hashCode() method.  Why doesn't that method meet your needs?

Comment: have you tried Eclipse's "Generate hashCode() and equals()" function? It's in one of the menus.

Comment: Sure - but beware of (tools that / writing) hash code algorithms that generate hashes on mutable values.

Comment: Joshua Bloch tells you how to write equals and hashCode properly in "Effective Java" chapter 3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try the [`HashCodeBuilder`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/HashCodeBuilder.html) from Apache Commons Lang. It's able to generate a hash code reflectively as follows:

```
public int hashCode() {
    return HashCodeBuilder.reflectionHashCode(this);
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Since Java 7, you have [Objects.hash()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#hash%28java.lang.Object...%29)

```
return Objects.hash(this.foo, this.bar, this.baz);
```

it also helps implementing equals:

```
return Objects.equals(this.foo, o.foo)
       && Objects.equals(this.bar, o.baz)
       && Objects.equals(this.baz, o.baz)
```

Comment: +1 Never knew about that until now.

Comment: Thanks, that helps, although I think this option is only just available to Android which is the environment I am tinkering with at the moment.

Comment: @user3079275 next time you ask a question about android, add the android tag to your question, and make it clear in the question itself.

Answer (score 1):

There's a helper class from Apache Commons-Lang project, named [`HashCodeBuilder`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.3/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/HashCodeBuilder.html). You can use it in each and every `hashCode` you need, or you could play with reflection (maybe with the help of some other library if you follow some pattern, like Java Bean) to iterate the fields recursively - but must be very careful to define when to stop and avoid endless loops.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use Guava **on a daily basis**. What you need is [Hasher](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/hash/Hasher.html)

Comment: You mean [`Objects.hashCode()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Objects.html#hashCode%28java.lang.Object...%29), right? It has been created just for this job. And Java 7 has a similar functionality.

Comment: I think both should work